# How to set daterange from FullCalendar?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using FullCalendar and in that I want the functionality to select one date and from that a number of dates should be selected automatically (and I want this with the dates not the events).

I can't use jQuery UI because of some conflict issues. So I have used FullCalendar and want that functionality. Ao can any one give me any suggestions how to do this?

The kind of functionality I want with the FullCalendar is like this `[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t6y8bucx/)`.

Comment: Note that the error you received regarding accompanying links to jsfiddle with code was not put there to make you change the link to code. It was put there to get you to put the actual code from the jsfiddle in the question itself. Please do so.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below fullcalendar js to select and highlights multiple dates

```
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate(),
      m = date.getMonth(),
      y = date.getFullYear();
  $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    buttonText: {
      today: 'today',
      month: 'month',
      week: 'week',
      day: 'day'
    },
    events: eventsscript,
    selectable: true,
    selectHelper: true,


select: function (start, end, jsEvent, view) {
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar('addEventSource', [{
          start: start,
          end: end,
          rendering: 'background',
          block: true,
      }, ]);
      $("#calendar").fullCalendar("unselect");
    },
    selectOverlap: function(event) {
        return ! event.block;
    }
```